# Making predictable data structure with nested dictionary without resorting to Any

Tags: swift

I have the following dictionary:

```
let myDict: [String: Any] = [
  "first": [
    "message": "qqq",
    "extras": ["task": "first"]
  ],
  "second": [
    "message": "www",
    "extras": ["task": "second"]
  ],
  "third": [
    "message": "eee",
    "extras": ["task": "third"]
  ],
]
```

The strucure is predictable: the top keys (`first`, `second`, `third`) can have any name but they always contain one `message` string and one `extras` dictionary which in turn contains one `task` *whose value is the original top key*. The structure is fixed as it influences other parts of the system.

Right now `myDict` is a `[String: Any]` but it seems like this could be improved since all types are known. However, I’m struggling to come up with a solution for it, to the point I’m doubting if a `struct` is the way to go?

The number of keys in the dictionary varies, so maybe each of those should be a `struct` instead of the dictionary as a whole? I’m unsure.

Data will be referenced by keys, and *their contents* will then be included in other keys that produce JSON. That part is working though, I don’t need assistance to create the JSON.

Comment: Don't use a `Dictionary` to represent data in code. Use actual data structures - custom `struct`s are perfect for data models. If you do need to send these over the network or convert them to JSON for any other reason, make your types conform to `Codable` and use `JSONEncoder`/`JSONDecoder`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor **That is  my question**. I’m specifically struggling to make this representation into a custom data structure. That’s what I’m asking for help with.

Comment: The best data structure to use depends on how you will use the object. Will you be looking up data by the keys (first, second, third). Do you need to keep the order of the keys (your current dictionary does not, so maybe not). Will you be converting this to/from JSON? Please provide more context.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth To clarify, I (think I) care about each key working as a `struct` (or something else), not the dictionary as a whole. I will be looking up data by the keys. The order is irrelevant. I will convert it to JSON but not as is: it will be included into other keys (that part is working though; the dictionary as is works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure of the dictionary content is fixed then it is only two values you need to keep track of per element in the top dictionary. So the struct could be defined as

```
struct Message {
    let message: String
    let key: String
}
```

If you need to convert it to a dictionary then you can add a computed property:

```
var dictionaryRepresentation: [String: Any] {
    [key: ["message": message, "extras": ["task": key]] as [String : Any]]
}
```

An example

```
let array = [Message(message: "qqq", key: "first"), Message(message: "www", key: "second"), Message(message: "eee", key: "third")]
print(array.map(\.dictionaryRepresentation))
```

> [["first": ["extras": ["task": "first"], "message": "qqq"]], ["second": ["message": "www", "extras": ["task": "second"]]], ["third": ["message": "eee", "extras": ["task": "third"]]]]

To fully recreate the dictionary in the the question using the example array above one can use `reduce(into:)`

```
array.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key] = $1.dictionaryRepresentation}
```

Comment: This returns an array of dictionaries instead of a flat dictionary.

Comment: "This" was just an example of mapping the individual elements. If you want a flat dictionary you can easily use `reduce(into:)`

Answer (score 0):

Heavily inspired by Joakim’s solution but taking into account the requirement to look up messages by their key I came up with this:

```
struct Message {
    let message: String
    let key: String
}

extension Message {
    var dictionaryRepresentation: [String: Any] {
        ["message": message, "extras": ["task": key] as [String: Any]]
    }
}

struct Messages {
    private var messages = [String: Message]()
    
    mutating func add(_ message: String, withKey key: String) {
        messages[key] = Message(message: message, key: key)
    }
    
    func message(for key: String) -> Message? {
        messages[key]
    }
}

extension Messages {
    var dictionaryRepresentation: [String: Any] {
        messages.mapValues(\.dictionaryRepresentation)
    }
}
```

You build your message dictionary by adding messages:

```
var myMessages = Messages()
myMessages.add("qqq", withKey: "first")
myMessages.add("www", withKey: "second")
myMessages.add("eee", withKey: "third")
```

You can look up a message:

```
if let secondMessage = myMessages.message(for: "second") {
    print("second message is \(secondMessage)")
    print("second message as dictionary is \(secondMessage.dictionaryRepresentation)")
}
```

> second message is Message(message: "www", key: "second")
>
> second message as dictionary is ["message": "www", "extras": ["task": "second"]]

And you can get a dictionary representation of all the messages:

```
print(myMessages.dictionaryRepresentation)
```

> ["second": ["message": "www", "extras": ["task": "second"]], "third": ["extras": ["task": "third"], "message": "eee"], "first": ["message": "qqq", "extras": ["task": "first"]]]

You could extend `Messages` with an initialiser that takes an array of keys and messages or a dictionary of key:message strings.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [answer by Joakim Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75930407/1661012), an alternative which avoids `Any`:

```
struct Message: Codable {
  let key: String
  let details: Details

  init(key: String, message: String) {
    self.key = key
    self.details = Details(message: message, extras: ["task": key])
  }

  struct Details: Codable {
    let message: String
    let extras: [String: String]
  }
}

let array = [Message(key: "first", message: "qqq"), Message(key: "second", message: "www"), Message(key: "third", message: "eee")]
let dict = array.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key] = $1.details }
```

To convert it to JSON:

```
import Foundation

let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(dict)
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
```